# Rendering deleted state array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array in a functional component state

```js
const [msg, setMsg] = useState([]); // mesage history
```

This array contains objects like this:

```
id: "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"
message: "1234"
sender: "i1dZb5"
time: "4:10 pm"
```

Now I am rendering this array using `map` function and providing `id` of the object as the key. However, on clicking the button which is supposed to delete the array contents and skip the `map` part, the page still renders the array, when some new message is added to the array, which has been deleted by the button. It can be seen in the console that the state does contain empty array but on clicking the show button the array suddenly gets populated by the deleted objects.

```
msg.map((val) => {
                              return (
                                    <div key={val.id} className={val.sender == name ? "msg-me" : "msg-box"}>
                                          <div className="sender">{val.sender} | {val.time}</div>
                                          { 
                                                val.sender == name ?
                                                <div className="msg">{val.message}</div>
                                                :
                                                <div className="msg" style={{color: "#000"}}>{val.message}</div>
                                          }
                                    </div>
                              )
                        })
```

EDIT: Here's the whole component, it's supposed to be a very basic chat app. Page 0 = join/create room page. Page 1 = chat page

```
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';
import './App.css';
import rsa from 'js-crypto-rsa';
import moment from 'moment';

let socket;
let pb, pv, serverKey;

function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0); // page index
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState([]); // mesage history
  const [name, setName] = useState(''); // name of the user
  const [room, setRoom] = useState(''); // room number
  const [curr, setCurr] = useState(''); // current message
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  const handleName = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleRoom = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRoom(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleCurr = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCurr(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(msg);
  }, [msg]);

  const handleClick = i => {
    if (i == 0) {
      setMsg([]);
      // create room button
      socket.emit('create', {
        name: name,
        public_key: pb,
      });
      setPage(1);
    } else if (i == 1) {
      setMsg([]);
      // join room button
      socket.emit('join', {
        room_id: parseInt(room, 10),
        name: name,
        public_key: pb,
      });

      setPage(1);
    } else if (i == 2) {
      setMsg([]);
      // leave
      setPage(0);
      setCurr('');
      setRoom('');
    } else if (i == 3) {
      // send button
      if (curr != '') {
        // send non empty string
        let uint = new TextEncoder();
        rsa
          .encrypt(uint.encode(curr), serverKey, 'SHA-256')
          .then(enc => {
            console.log('outgoing message to the server', enc);
            socket.emit('message', {message: enc});
          })
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
      }
      setCurr(''); // clear input
    }
  };

  // generate random name
  function gen_name(length) {
    let result = '';
    let characters =
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setName(gen_name(6)); // assign random name initially

    rsa
      .generateKey(2048)
      .then(key => {
        pb = key.publicKey;
        pv = key.privateKey;
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

    socket = io('http://localhost:4000', {transports: ['websocket']}); // connect to backend

    // listen to messages
    socket.on('message', data => {
      let temp = msg;
      console.log('incoming message from server', data.message);
      rsa
        .decrypt(new Uint8Array(data.message), pv, 'SHA-256')
        .then(dec => {
          // console.log(dec);
          let dec_msg = new TextDecoder().decode(dec);
          // console.log(dec_msg);
          temp.push({
            sender: data.name,
            message: dec_msg,
            time: moment.utc(Date.now()).local().format('h:mm a'),
            id: gen_name(1024),
          });
          setMsg([...temp]);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
      divRef.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
    });

    // listen for room number if created
    socket.on('room', data => {
      setRoom(data.room);
    });

    socket.on('key', data => {
      serverKey = data.key; // server's public key
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect(); // remove listeners
    };
  }, []);

  //   if (page == 0) { // first page
  //         return (
  //               <div className="App">
  //                     <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleClick(0)}>Create Room</button>
  //                     <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>Join Room</button>
  //                     <div className="card">
  //                           <p>Enter your name</p>
  //                           <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleName} />
  //                     </div>
  //                     <div className="card">
  //                           <p>Enter room number to join</p>
  //                           <input type="text" value={room} onChange={handleRoom} />
  //                     </div>
  //               </div>
  //         );
  //   }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {page == 1 ? (
        <>
          <div className="messages">
            {msg.map(val => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={val.id}
                  className={val.sender == name ? 'msg-me' : 'msg-box'}
                >
                  <div className="sender">
                    {val.sender} | {val.time}
                  </div>
                  {val.sender == name ? (
                    <div className="msg">{val.message}</div>
                  ) : (
                    <div className="msg" style={{color: '#000'}}>
                      {val.message}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div className="card">
            <input
              className="msg-input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Type your message here"
              value={curr}
              onChange={handleCurr}
            />
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => handleClick(3)} className="btn">
              Send
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => handleClick(2)} className="btn">
              Leave
            </button>
            <p>Room: {room}</p>
          </div>
          <div ref={divRef} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleClick(0)}>
            Create Room
          </button>
          <button className="btn" onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>
            Join Room
          </button>
          <div className="card">
            <p>Enter your name</p>
            <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleName} />
          </div>
          <div className="card">
            <p>Enter room number to join</p>
            <input type="text" value={room} onChange={handleRoom} />
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: We would need to see the delete function, otherwise, it's difficult to diagnose the issue. But it would also be good to see the whole component. So you could provide a reproducible example

Comment: @TheTisiboth I've added the whole component. There's no delete function as such, but when clicking the leave button I am using `setMsg([])`.

Comment: Thank for the code. Sadly I'm not able to run it locally, I'm getting an error linked to the encrypt package. Can you provide a reproducible example, for example here: https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Ah but a backend is required, isn't it? Then I can only make assumptions. First, you are checking equality with ==, but I guess you would like either to check equality with ===.
Also, in line 106, where you receive incoming messages, I would rather do this:
const temp = [...msg], so you are getting a copy of msg

Comment: @TheTisiboth using `const temp = [..msg]` won't let the `push` function work when getting new message. Therefore, only one message is visible all the time. I will try to make a reproducible example